# Styled component, breaks on google chrome

Tags: javascript, reactjs, styled-components

Styled component breaks on google chrome when changing the prop (form true to false for example). When props are changed styled component outputs class with no CSS inside, while on Firefox everything works as expected.

Here is the very part of the code

```
const PeriodsHolder = styled.div`
    justify-content: ${props => (props.childCount ? "baseline" : "center")}
    flex-wrap: nowrap !important;
    overflow-x: scroll;
    margin: 0 -5px;
    min-height: 90vh;
    display: flex;
    flex-wrap: wrap;
    margin-right: -15px;
    margin-left: -15px;
    @media(min-width: 980px){
      flex: 0 0 75%;
      max-width: 75%;
  }
`
```

Answer (score 1):

You are missing a semicolon at the end of the first line.

```
justify-content: ${props => (props.childCount ? "baseline" : "center")}
                                                                     ^^^^^
```

The rest of the styles are being ignored.

Comment: Thanks a lot for answer,but it didn't work in this case. I did add it but behavior is the same.

Comment: @ZlatanBekric Its not possible my friend - `justify-content: ${props => props.childCount ? "baseline" : "center"};` has to work properly

Comment: Thanks a lot @kinduser, problem was actually with loom extension for chrome. Here is a link to issue opened on github https://github.com/styled-components/styled-components/issues/2885

Comment: @ZlatanBekric Good to hear that you found the problem, cheers!